# Implement .net Control with Native C++

Tags: c#, c++, firebreath

Is it possible to add .net control like textbox or button in native window i.e forms created in c++ with Firebreath Framework. Please let me know for the same.

Comment: Mostly probably yes, but it would require so much effort, that it probably is not worth it.

Comment: Since it's mentioned that Firebreath produces ActiveX components you should be able to use them from .NET, try adding the dll of the component as a reference to a e.g. C# project and examine what is loaded from it.

Comment: The point of using Firebreath is to create plugins that work on any browser.  You could only get Winforms controls going as an ActiveX control in IE.  So there's no point.